# Image load event not working on second page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails 4.2 app (no turbolinks) where I want to wait for an image to load before doing something with js. I used the jquery load callback

```
$(image).load(function() {
    // do something here
});
```

and expected everything to be good however it only works on a hard reload (command + shift + R on osx). If I navigate by clicking a link then the image load event never fires, the image doesn't show up on the page but the DOM says it's there. I've already figured out a workaround using a promise instead but I'm curious for some insight into why this strange behaviour could arise?

Comment: On safari browser? I had recently an issue with safari, load event wasn't working on back event, cause Safari caches the content so the js was not executed.

Comment: browser is cached the image, i guess.

Comment: So what is the alternative to load event? What's interesting in this case is when it is loaded and available in the DOM.

Comment: @rorykoehler Did you try putting the load function inside ready function?

Comment: @Sebin ... is inside a document ready function already. This is why I assumed it would trigger even if cached.